# Cannot run apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, package-management

If I try to install anything APT wants me to run `sudo apt-get -f install`

However, if I run that I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-git2-glib-1.0 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-zeitgeist-2.0
  libgit2-glib-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
705 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 435973 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick workaround would be force overwriting  the file that caused the error, be careful though:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Followed by fix install:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

**Overwriting thing can produce serious trouble if you did it wrong, make sure you are know what you are doing !**

Comment: It is unwise to work around a file conflict - it will recur every time either package is upgraded, and will completely break a release upgrade. Please file a bug report - no other package should be providing libc-bin files.